# what is role of value attributes

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new in React. I wonder what `value={foo}` is used for. Even without this, I can do what I want. Second input doesn't have value attribute, but it works.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);
  const [bar, setBar] = useState(0);

  const multi = useMemo(() => {
    return foo * bar;
  }, [foo, bar]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={foo}
        onChange={e => {
          setFoo(parseInt(e.target.value));
        }}
      />
      <input
        onChange={e => {
          setBar(parseInt(e.target.value));
        }}
      />
      <div>{multi}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is it for data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Value attributes in case input fields. It is used in  set the value in input that what you want to give the value to input fields. and like in form submission we can have the form input values.

```js
function getVal(ev) {
console.log(ev.target.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="some value" onkeyup="getVal(event)">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But without value attribute it works same. Is it used as a placeholder?